# Accessing internal expando id for an element

Tags: jquery

I've been having issues with on/off removing event handlers that I don't want to, and would like to namespace the event binding with the html element's expando id.

```
function SomeWidget(el) {
   $(document).on('handler.MY_EXPANDO_ID', this.handler.bind(this));
};
var widget = new SomeWidget($(sometargetelement));
```

The problem with not having a unique identifier, is that currently I have namespaces the same, which screws up when I have two widgets of the same time, and one removed, it removed the handler for both objects.

Question 1) How do I access an elements' internal expando id?
Question 2) Is there a better way to do this?  Function.bind !== Function, which makes removing based on the actual method pointer not possible

I'm using jQuery 1.8.3

Comment: that jquery736871587563262132125 we see from time to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI's widget factory increments a counter whenever a widget is created.  Then they have an `eventNamespace` property available for exactly this reason.  You could accomplish the same type of thing:

```
function SomeWidget(el) {
    SomeWidget.instances++;
    var eventNamespace = ".SomeWidget" + SomeWidget.instances;

    $(el).on("handler" + eventNamespace, ...);
}
SomeWidget.instances = 0;
```

This will increment the instances whenever a new `SomeWidget` is created.  Internally it will have access to an `eventNamespace` that can be used for binding / unbinding events.

If you needed access outside of your widget, you could store the `eventNamespace` as data on the element:

```
$(el).data("eventNamespace", eventNamespace);
```

However, this would be overwritten if you created multiple instances of the widget with the same element.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm currently doing, I was just wondering if I could re-use this id

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would want to reuse the unique event namespace?

Comment: I thought it was a unique id attached to the element, not an event -- am I wrong here?

Comment: No, its purpose is to give each event a unique name so that a specific event can be unbound later.  `.off('click')` will unbind all click events.  `.off('click.bob')` will only unbind events that were bound with `.on('click.bob', fn)`.  [jQuery Event Namespace documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events)

Comment: Yeah I got that -- I was under the assumption that id was for the element, not for the event.  Thanks!